# laravel: How to call controller function from a component

Tags: laravel, components, rss-reader

I have a rss feed (world news) section in sidebar of page. That sidebar will be visible in all pages.

Hence I thought to make component of sidebar since it is for all page. But rss feed I am using [willvincent/feeds](https://packagist.org/packages/willvincent/feeds) calls feed via function from controller.

It is working fine until I call it from view. But when I switch to component then it is showing undefined variable (var in foreach).

Is there a way to use controller function directly in component? Or is there any other work around?

Comment: what you are looking for is view composer https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers. You can also differ the rss feed and call it via ajax after page render

Comment: We need more information/code to help. For example you can pass variables from your view to your component if needed, or get the variable from your component class, calling the controller function from a component is not the right way in my opinion